# Error MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, lumen

NotFoundHttpException at 
Application->handleDispatcherResponse(array(2,array(GET,POST))

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () use ($router) {
$router->post('contingent', ['as' => 'createContingent','uses' =>  'ContingentController@showById']);
$router->get('contingent', 'ContingentController@showAllContingent');
}
```

i access this POST routes in angular 4 :

```
$router->post('contingent', ['as' => 'createContingent','uses' =>  'ContingentController@showById']);
```

And then the error is :

MethodNotAllowedHttpException

at Application->handleDispatcherResponse(array(2,array(GET,POST)) in RoutesRequest.php line 164

is there error in my lumen aplication or in angular 4?

Comment: What route are you trying to get/post to? You can use `php artisan route:list` on the command line to verify the routes.

Comment: i'm trying to post

Comment: To what route? Show the exact route. If you don't have too many routes, show the output for `php artisan route:list`

Comment: edited. i have many routes, i cant show that

Comment: Can you show how you are invoking the POST request?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot to put the prefix `api/` in your `routes` when you are calling it. Try this `your_domain.com/api/contingent` with `GET` or `POST` request